Can anyone recognize these models?
I bought these models. 21 models titled Warhammer soldiers. They were used and painted. At first I thought they were part of Astra militarum or Death Korps of Krieg, but when I looked online I couldn’t find any match.
18 models are really similar. 1 is like the others except with a antenna supporting a skull icon. 2 last models are different than the rest.
I wish to fix them and repaint them, but first I would like to know who these are and what they are about. So can anyone help?


It's not much to go on, but the icon looks a little like the Star of Chaos as shown at https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Chaos, so that figure at least may not be Imperial at all.

How heavy are they? (compared to similarly size plastic / metal models)
